# How can I get the same id of two different arrays using $.each jquery function

Tags: jquery

This is my way of getting the values of my array in my $.each. Im getting the value of model and quantity of each one. The reserved_qty is the value from my table. This is my query.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(backup_sales.model_id) as ReservedQTY FROM backup_sales 
              LEFT JOIN product_model ON backup_sales.model_id = product_model.model_id 
              LEFT JOIN brand ON brand.brand_id = product_model.brand_id 
              LEFT JOIN client ON client.client_id =backup_sales.client_id 
              LEFT JOIN company ON company.company_id = client.company_id 
              WHERE backup_sales.po_ID = '".$_GET['po_ID']."'
              GROUP BY backup_sales.model_id, backup_sales.client_id");


//Reserved Qtys Function
$('input[name^="reserved_qty"]', '#tblEdit').each(function(){
  obj = {};
  if (this.className == "" && this.value == "0"){
    return this.value;
  }
  else
  {
    obj["model"] = this.className;
    obj["reserved_qty"] = this.value;
  }
  my_arr.push(obj);
});

//Input Qtys Function
$('input[name^="quantity"]', '#tblEdit').each(function(){
  obj = {};
  if (this.className == "" && this.value == "0"){
    return this.value;
  }
  else
  {
    obj["model_id"] = this.className;
    obj["input_quantity"] = this.value;
  }
  dataObs.push(obj);
});
```

And this is my way of displaying each value and assigning my 2 arrays.

```
   $.each(my_arr, function(index, value){
    $.each(dataObs, function(subIndex, val){
    console.log(value);
    console.log(val);
  });
});
```

I want my value to become

```
{model: "1", reserved_qty: "4"} 
{model_id: "1", input_quantity: "4"} 
{model_id: "3", input_quantity: "3"} 
{model: "3", reserved_qty: "3"} 
{model: "4", reserved_qty: "3"} 
{model_id: "4", input_quantity: "3"}
```

As of now my value is keep on getting these values

```
{model: "1", reserved_qty: "4"} 
{model_id: "3", input_quantity: "3"} 
{model: "1", reserved_qty: "4"} 
{model_id: "4", input_quantity: "3"} 
{model: "3", reserved_qty: "3"} 
{model_id: "1", input_quantity: "4"} 
{model: "3", reserved_qty: "3"} 
{model_id: "4", input_quantity: "3"}
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged `php`?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you sir/madam.

Comment: I suggest you simply remove that tag, it _is_ confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but because you have nested loops you will need to check for each iteration of the inner loop to ensure that the `model` matches the `model_id`. Otherwise it will output each database row for every entry in the form (your outer loop).

Something like this:

```
 $.each(my_arr, function(index, value){
    $.each(dataObs, function(subIndex, val){
    if (value.model == val.model_id) { // you need to check model vs model_id here
       console.log(value);
       console.log(val);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes we do have the same answer on my question. Thank you sir!